# white space at top of page between status bar and body

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4 and I have a white space between the status bar and body, I'm trying to add `margin-top:-1px` and it's solved my problem, but I ask to know if there's another possible solution for that problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this `{ position: absolute; top : 0px; }` to set the toolbar correctly.

This happens because your `<ion-header>` is a child to other containers such as `<router-outlet>`. So there is a gap in rendering your `<ion-header>`.

Comment: Could you check your app.component.html to see if you are rendering anything else before router-outlet.